# PHP get text between a string and another

Tags: php, regex

So I have a lot of text in a text file that acts like a "database" and I need to extract a specific part that starts from a string and ends with another one.
To be more specific, some of the "database" looks like this:

```
i:24;s:5:"sName";s:12:"adsfasdffdfd";s:7:"iStatus";i:1;s:9:"iPosition";i:0;s:17:"sDescriptionShort";s:29:"<p>test short description</p>";s:16:"sDescriptionFull";s:28:"<p>test full description</p>";
```

And I need to extract the part between `<p>` and `</p>` having as parameter the first `i:24`, the number being the parameter.
I tried using regexp but no success until now.
Now I know it's not good practice asking for code itself but this time I'm really stuck! Any ideas?
P.S. The file contains strings like this one after another. So I need the regexp to find a `i:$a` with `$a` my number and return the content from the first paragraph it encounters.
So what I expect to be returned is: `<p>test short description</p>`
Considering this should be the first paragraph encountered AFTER `i:24`

Comment: This seems more like a invalid serialized string.

Comment: I know but the CMS puts the whole content like this... :(

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with the CMS. This seems like it should be a serialized string. Try to fix the real cause of this instead of implementing a new one with a unnecessary regex.

Comment: You can use: `i:24.*?\K<p>[^<]*</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for text that comes after the literals `i:24`? Since none of these are special characters, let's begin our pattern construction with that literal sequence...

```
i:24
```

Next there may or may not be more characters to consume between the `i:24` and the opening `<p>` tag. Let's assume that these characters can be anything, so we'll use a wildcard metacharacter with the `{,INF}` quantifier, `*` giving us...

```
i:24.*
```

We want to tame the regex engine's appetite so let's modify our quantifier by making it non-greedy.

```
i:24.*?
```

Next we want to match AND CAPTURE an opening, `<p>`...

```
i:24.*?(<p>)
```

...and the content inside of the `<p>` tag, which we'll assume can be anything (read wildcard) and maybe nothing, `{,INF}`, or `*`.

```
i:24.*?(<p>.*)
```

Remember to tame our `*` quantifier's appetite so that it doesn't consume too many `<p>` tags.

```
i:24.*?(<p>.*?)
```

And finally we'll close it off by consuming and capturing the closing `</p>` tag, with the escaped forward-slash, since it's a special character.

```
i:24.*?(<p>.*?<\/p>)
```

Hope this works for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation is very clean and easy to understand. Great content :)